# Can LDA model be useful for sentences (not documents) clustering / classification?

Tags: pyspark, cluster-analysis, text-mining, text-classification, lda

Recently, I’m working on sentence classification problem, these sentences are nothing but one or two line of reviews about product and customers post there feedback on various features that product has to offer. After pre-processing (removal of stop words and stemming)  I’m using feature extraction libraries  (like word2vec, tf-idf) and clustering algorithms (k-mean) to run over my sentences to have unsupervised sentence classification - output is fairly acceptable. However I’m looking for more options on clustering algorithm, specifically wanted to try out LDA to  further improve quality of output however I have come across [this](https://www-ljk.imag.fr/membres/Marianne.Clausel/Fichiers/SentenceLDA.pdf) paper listing few facts on LDA for using on sentence classification.

My question is – Would be helpful to use LDA on sentence (not documents) classification? Also apart from K-mean what are other alternative with unsupervised learning that that can work well with sentence classification. Thank you in advance for all your suggestion.

Note: I’m practicing my exercise in Spark 1.6.1 environment with pyspark API.

## After Trying out LDA by myself, below is output:

1 Topics came out similar: frequent words for each of the topics overlap a lot and topics share almost the same set of words.

[image]

One of my understanding was, my reviews belongs to specific domain. For example my product belong to credit card domain & all reviews revolving around this singl domain. Further, I tried to plot word distribution and found that most frequently use word is just around 2% of total population.

Comment: I don't see how that author-less paper relates to your problem. It's meant to accelerate LDA by doing a more coarse sentence-level rather than word-level model. Why don't you just try LDA?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to try it by myself. Our enterprise version of spark 1.6.1 (http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/ml-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda) doesn't support python base API for LDA  however spark 2.0 does have it ( http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/ml-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda) . Enterprise upgrade with infra team does take little longer. Meanwhile I'm trying to see if anyone has previous knowledge and can share experience on it. I'm working on evaluating output, shall share my personal learnings.

Comment: Try without Spark. You don't need to scale when you don't know what works yet. And Spark often is much slower than a good C implementation, you can't take it as a reference. It is also very limited in functionality - so it may not work in Spark, but does work in better tools.

Answer (score 2):

The overlapping is not necessarily a function of your input (documents or sentences) but could well be the result of your hyperparameter choices.  For example, you could choose lower alpha to have less overlap over topics.

From
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37405/natural-interpretation-for-lda-hyperparameters

> In practice, a high alpha-value will lead to documents being more similar in terms of what topics they contain. A high beta-value will similarly lead to topics being more similar in terms of what words they contain.

Answer (score 2):

"""
Distinct from our proposed “one
topic per sentence” assumption, all these methods
allow each sentence to include multiple topics, and
use various means to incorporate sentence structure.
The most straightforward method is to treat each
sentence as a document and apply the LDA model
on the collection of sentences rather than documents.
Despite its simplicity, this method, called local-LDA
(Brody and Elhadad 2010), has been demonstrated to
be effective in discovering meaningful topics while
summarizing consumer reviews. (p.1376) 
"""
see: https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/pdf/10.1287/mnsc.2014.1930

Answer (score 1):

Yes. LDA *can* also work on sentences (but won't always work).

It tends to work better on longer documents though. But your sentences are longer than tweets, that's good.

Comment: Alright.Thanks for your comments. Let me try running LDA on reviews statements and evaluate results, shall get back to you shortly.

Comment: Updated comments after trying out LDA on my data.